# Include date on my query with my top ten users?

Tags: mysql, sql

I already have this query:

```
SELECT usuario,SUM(hojas)AS sum 
FROM trabajo 
GROUP BY usuario 
ORDER BY SUM DESC 
LIMIT 0,10 ;
```

which is working perfectly, but I want to discriminate by **month, day and year**, but I don't know how to include it. I've already tried with this:

```
SELECT usuario,SUM(hojas)AS sum 
FROM trabajo 
GROUP BY usuario 
ORDER BY SUM DESC 
LIMIT 0,10 
WHERE MONTH(fecha)='5';
```

which means I only want top ten data from May, but It doesn't work... sorry I'm really noob and new with MySQL. thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, format your post.

Comment: `WHERE` has to go between `FROM` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Any SQL tutorial should show the proper order of clauses in a query. You're not allowed to rearrange it, you have to use that order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement should look by the following:

```
SELECT usuario,SUM(hojas)AS sum 
FROM trabajo 
WHERE MONTH(fecha)='5' 
GROUP BY usuario 
ORDER BY SUM DESC 
LIMIT 0,10;
```

You can find more information about formatting here:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: thanks i forgot to check this but it was exactly what i did and it worked